# What is the font in the Profmat logo?

Tags: font-identification

I need to redraw the logo below but I don't know what the font is. Help is welcome.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried contacting the company to see if they have a hi-res or vector version of the logo they can supply? If the logo is being used legitimately, they should be happy to provide a better version than having it redrawn, possibly violating their own branding guidelines.

Comment: @PhilipRegan, I'd just asked by e-mail. Lets see. Thanks.

Comment: Whoever drew that logo, they misaligned the "A".

Comment: @JoeZeng, also the `P`, it is not closed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like a modified version of [Peignot](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/peignot/) to me.

[image]

Comment: It *is* Piegnot Demi, but the linked typeface is not actually the typeface "Peignot"

Comment: ACTUALLY, I take that back: the logo is a mixture of uppercase and lowercase letters normalized for height & size. That typeface looks correct.

Comment: The P is different.

Comment: The P is probably an R with the descender clipped off. You will need to modify it or mask it.

Comment: All that to say what I said originally: It's a *modified* version of Piegnot. Not extensively so, making the OP's job much easier.

Answer (score 2):

If that's the only image you have, you'll have more luck **redrawing it entirely in curves** than trying to find a match ([there is none in WhatTheFont](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/results?ch%5B0%5D=P&ch%5B1%5D=R&ch%5B2%5D=&ch%5B3%5D=O&ch%5B4%5D=&ch%5B5%5D=F&ch%5B6%5D=&ch%5B7%5D=M&ch%5B8%5D=A&ch%5B9%5D=T&wtfserver=rsc_wtf4&id=0003b18e50f04257000f3f4a0000054f&glyphcount=10&imageid=0&x=62&y=31))

You can redraw the logo using Inkscape, Illustrator or similar. Just paste the image in a payer and lock it, and draw the logo on top of it (you then need to get rid of the original bitmap).

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that I don't have a high resolution image to redraw it. So it's difficult to do a good job.

Comment: Of course you do, look: http://www.ufsj.edu.br/portal2-repositorio/Image/profmat/profmat.jpg Just do a search for Profmat in google images (almost always works!)